# Set request format in Rails test being overriden by defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, format, rails-routing

I have a `namespace` defined in my `config/routes.rb` that sets the default format for requests for a controller to `json`. I would like to write a test that makes a request to this controller using a different format but it doesn't seem to work.

**config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :foo, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :bars
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/foo/bars_controller.rb**

```
class Foo::BarsController < ActionController::API
  before_action :print_request_format

  def print_request_format
    puts "Request format is #{request.format}"
  end
end
```

**test/integration/format_test.rb**

```
class FormatTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "XML request" do
    get foo_bars_path, format: "xml"
    assert_match /application\/xml/, request.format

    # Assert other stuff for handling XML.
  end
end
```

When I run the test, the assertion fails and the output is `Request format is application/json`, so the `format: "xml"` is being ignored or overridden by the defaults in the routes file. Is there any way I can specify the format in the test and not have it overriden?

Comment: According to the documentation (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults) default values are available as params like `params[:format]`. I am not shure `request` object is affected by default options

Comment: The params aren't changed either when I use the above approach.

Comment: Any update ? :)

Comment: @Antzi Nope, sorry; I don't think I ever solved it.